# drawRect with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have this code for `UIVIew`:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let toolbarSize = CGFloat(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? 0 : 54)

    let width = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)
    let height = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - toolbarSize

    let heightSpan = floor(height / 2 - self.cropSize.height / 2)
    let widthSpan = floor(width / 2 - self.cropSize.width / 2)

    // fill outer rect
    UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).set()
    UIRectFill(self.bounds)

    // fill inner border
    UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5).set()
    UIRectFrame(CGRectMake(widthSpan - 2, heightSpan - 2, self.cropSize.width + 4,
        self.cropSize.height + 4))

    // fill inner rect
    UIColor.clearColor().set()
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(widthSpan, heightSpan, self.cropSize.width, self.cropSize.height))
}
```

This draws a rect with a white border to my `UIView`, I want to add a corner radius to draw a circle.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: if corner radius and border color is what u need, there is no need to disturb drawRect. YOu can simply set corner radius property and border color of a uiview.

Comment: "*I want to add a corner radius to draw a circle*", have you had a look at `CGContextFillEllipseInRect`?

Comment: `UIBezierPath` is not an option?

Comment: any example of this?

Comment: Please refer to **Rect with Rounded Corners: Use a Path.**

Answer (score 6):

**Rect with Rounded Corners: Use a Path.**

Unless you want to apply the rounded corners to the entire view (easiest) or to a sublayer (most flexible) using `layer.cornerRadius`, you draw *roundedRect* with a `UIBezierPath`.
A square *roundedRect* with a `cornerRadius` of 1/2 the height ends up being a circle or a disc.

```swift
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect,cornerRadius: 10)
path.fill()
```

**3 roundedRect at your disposal:**

```swift
let regular   = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat)
let irregular = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect,
                        byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner, cornerRadii: CGSize)
let oval      = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect)
```

Use `path.stroke()` for border, `path.fill()` for content.

---

**Example in your drawRect context:**

```swift
// fill inner rect
UIColor.clearColor().set()
let innerRect = CGRectMake(widthSpan, heightSpan,
                           self.cropSize.width, self.cropSize.height)

// replace UIRectFill(innerRect) by:
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect, cornerRadius: 10)
path.fill()
```

---

Inspired by this [excellent](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/code-for-ios-7-rounded-rectangles) discussion:

```m
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
             cornerRadius: 10];
path.lineWidth = 1;
[UIColor.clearColor setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Answer (score 5):

this works nice for me

```
    someImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    someImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    someImageView.layer.cornerRadius = someImageView.frame.height/2
    someImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code in `awakeFromNib`.
Code below works pretty good for me

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
self.authorAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = self.authorAvatar.frame.size.width/2;
self.authorAvatar.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

I use that in custom cell. Also you can use same code in custom view.